# How server accept AJAX but block CURL request that coming with "X-Requested-With" header?

Tags: ajax, curl

I have a page called "endpoint.php".

This endpoint must be called by AJAX in the same domain.
and also, I have a .htaccess file to restrict "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://myserver.com"
```

But, when I use CURL from a different domain, with the "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" header, the endpoint is still accessible and display the result as using ajax method from the same domain.

endpoint.php

```
// using codeigniter input class
if($this->input->is_ajax_request())
{
    echo "I'm AJAX";
}
else
{
    echo "NOT AJAX";
}
```

ajax.php

```
$.ajax({
    url: "endpoint.php",
    success: function(r){
        console.log(r);
        // display: I'm AJAX
    }
});
```

curl.php (located in different domain)

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://myserver.com/endpoint.php",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest")
));
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $resp; // result: I'm AJAX
```

In this situation, how to accept AJAX request but blocks the CURL request comes with an "X-Requested-With" header.